# How do command line utility gems work?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do gems like "rails", "rspec", and "cucumber" allow user to use commands that start with their gem name??

```
rails new project
rspec spec
cucumber features
```

Not all gems have this ability. For example, when I type `json` even though I have it installed, I get

```
-bash: json: command not found
```

Comment: check this out: https://practicingruby.com/articles/building-unix-style-command-line-applications?u=dc2ab0f9bb

Comment: Not your question, but slightly related: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/nicksieger/jsonpretty looking at your example this might be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gem's .gemspec file looks like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = "haml"
  s.version = "3.1.8"

  ....

   s.executables = ["haml", "html2haml"]
end
```

This means that when installing this Gem (haml-3.1.8 in this case) also links to executables (also called "binstubs") will be created for the files `haml` and `html2haml` which are found inside the gem's bin/ directory.

In this case, for example the file `bin/haml` could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'haml'

puts Haml::VERSION
```

Answer (score 4):

From [rubygems.org documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) on building Gems:

> In addition to providing libraries of Ruby code, gems can also expose
>   one or many executable files to your shell’s PATH. Probably the best
>   known example of this is rake. Another very useful one is
>   prettify_json.rb, included with the JSON gem, which formats JSON in a
>   readable manner (and is included with Ruby 1.9).
>
> [...]
>
> Adding an executable to a gem is a simple process. You just need to
>   place the file in your gem’s bin directory, and then add it to the
>   list of executables in the gemspec. Let’s add one for the Hola gem.
>
> [...]
>
> The executable file itself just needs a shebang in order to figure out
>   what program to run it with.
>
> [...]
>
> All it’s doing is loading up the gem, and passing the first command
>   line argument as the language to say hello with.

Answer (score 1):

These gems have binaries that can be executed from the CLI. Most gems do not need this functionality and only provide code extensions.

Edit: They may not be 'binaries'. They can be just executable Ruby code as well. Thanks @holger

Comment: Typically, these are just executables consisting of plain ruby code. They are not necessarily binaries.